# How to extract table details into rows and columns using pdfplumber

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdfplumber

I am using pdfplumber to extract tables from pdf. But the table in use does not have visible vertical lines separating content so the the data extracted are into 3 rows and one huge column.

[image: sample screenshot of pdf table - grey boxes are text just hidden]

I would like the above table to come into 13 rows.

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
with pdfplumber.open('test.pdf') as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    tables = page.extract_tables()

print(tables)
```

From the documentation I could not understand if there was a specific table settings I could apply. I tried some but it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried to split them using whitelines ?, Can you share sample data.

Comment: splitting using whitelines does not solve it as some text have multiple words...this is the data result.  \n [['Text'], ['0000000 10:53:21 51748756 10:53:21 text. text 24 101.30 0.30 101.60 0.00 -2438.49  text'], ['000000 10:53:21 51748757 10:53:21 text. text 2 101.30 0.30 101.60 0.00 -203.21  text'], ['05439969 10:53:21 000000 10:53:21 text. text 74 101.30 0.30 101.60 0.00 -7518.69  text'], ['Code :  000000 Scrip Total 100 -10160.39']]

Comment: Would be much better if you share sample data to here you here.

Comment: There are certain personal details that I literally cannot share in a public platform which have been replaced by the word 'text'. Believe me if I could, I would to help solve this problem faster.

Comment: Well you can replace personal data with dummy ones (especially the text ones), otherwise not sure if anyone can here, we need raw data to help you..

Comment: ok here you go. https://pdfhost.io/edit?doc=d4251b75-f227-40cc-a9b9-2a905de9630f

Comment: Hey Walter please remove your uploaded file, there is sensitive data appearing when reading your file..

Answer (score 2):

Please add below settings when using `extract_tables()` option (This may need to be changed based on your input file) :

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with pdfplumber.open(r'document.pdf') as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]    
    table = page.extract_table(table_settings={"vertical_strategy": "lines", 
                                               "horizontal_strategy": "text", 
                                               "snap_tolerance": 4,})
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=table[0]).T
```

Morover, Please have a read on `pdfplumber` documentation (extracting-tables) section, as there is many options to include in your code based in your input file :

https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-tables

Comment: Firstly...The manner I require the data is without the transpose. With your suggestion of table settings, the data is still in a single column. I want that data to be in separate columns.  [https://imgur.com/a/oixzQEF]

Comment: can you please look into pdfplumber documentation (extracting-tables) section to adjust the settings based on your data..

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.DataFrame to customize your table instead of directly printing the table.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tables[1:], columns=tables[0])
for column in df.columns.tolist():
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace(" ", "")

print(df)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is doing but it is generating an error. 'AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 11 columns
'